# Is my rough design of wireless powered leds with a capacitance touch sensor reasonable?

Tags: led, battery-charging, wireless, capacitance, wireless-charging

Disclaimer:  I am not an engineer, but I have a background in physics, so theoretically I should know most of this stuff, but in reality, I might have made some very basic and dumb mistakes.

**The system at a glance:**
I want a system that wirelessly powers around 3-10 LEDs and includes a capacitance touch sensor and would like some feedback on whether I am on the right track or have forgotten anything.

My plan is to have a standard low-power wireless transmitter using the QI standard to deliver the power to the system. (I hope that the QI standard will be able to charge at distances slightly larger than 5mm, maybe 1 cm?, since I might not be able to bring the receiver closer than that to the transmitter.)

**Wireless receiver:**
The system itself will consist of a wireless receiver, I am thinking one of these:
[Search at Mouser.com for wireless receiver chips](https://www.mouser.dk/c/semiconductors/power-management-ics/wireless-charging-ics/?output%20power=1%20W%7E%7E5%20W&product=Receivers&rp=semiconductors%2Fpower-management-ics%2Fwireless-charging-ics%7C%7EOutput%20Power)
but which one? I guess most of them will probably do, but looking at the various different data sheets, I can't really say I know which ones makes the most sense. I guess the main thing to look out for here, is whether it also can monitor the battery status to know when to power the battery.

**Battery:**
Then I need a small battery of some kind, this battery does not need to be very powerful since the device will likely be placed on the wireless transmitter most of the time anyway. So maybe a battery that can that can power my setup for 8 hours of use.
I am considering a few rechargeable AA batteries in series/parallel such that they match the output voltage of the receiver. However, I do not know whether AA batteries will work in such a setup? or do I need a li-ion/lipo battery, in order for the communication with the wireless receiver? (I think this is the case). In that case, I just need a small battery such that the setup can hold power for maybe 8 hours of use. Any suggestions on battery type would be appreciated!

**Capacitance touch sensor:**
The next part is the capacitance touch sensor, [Search at Mouser.com for Capacitance touch sensors](https://www.mouser.dk/c/sensors/capacitive-touch-sensors/), once again there are many options, and some of them come with led drivers embedded, [like this one](https://www.mouser.dk/datasheet/2/268/CAP1114-477181.pdf), though I am not really sure I need that. I guess that is for if you want to be able to turn on each led individually. In my case I probably just want to turn on all of them at once, and since I will likely need to solder all of this by hand, I don't want anything too small, ideally.
In any case, my plan is to essentially use the capacitance touch sensor as a switch in my setup to turn on and off the LEDs.

**Led setup:**
Finally the LEDs themselves, I will only want one color of LEDs in a given setup, though I might do a few different setups with different colors. One thing I can't quite figure out here is whether I need a resistor with each LED if I place them in parallel (as seen here [image: led setup])
or whether I can just use one resistor before the parallel splitting? Assuming all of the LEDs are of the same kind, I would imagine one resistor should be fine?

**Background information:** I am trying to design LED mushrooms that I plan on installing in a piece of wood that I will hollow out to make room for the electronics. The capacitive touch sensors I will drill close to the surface from the inside of the wood but without going through, and the hope is that I should be able to activate them by then touching the wood in the appropriate spot. An example of what my final output might eventually look like: [image: Example image]

Comment: This is really 5-10 questions in one, and we offer advice for free, in exchange for "points" of recognition. You have asked for us to do way too much work for free, and we are not really a "bless your design" site.  That being said, I think the "touch sensor" and how you're trying to implement it will have the most challenges. If the material is damp at all, or likely to become damp, don't even try it.  You may have to try many things, or come to us many times with questions, to get a sensor working through the wood. Just promise me no X-Ray devices! ;-)

Comment: My suggestion is you ask one extremely specific question at a time.  Suggest starting with "How might I sense a touch through a quarter inch of dry wood?" and in the description say, "I thought I might try a touch sensor with this chip / this microcontroller". You'll have to work on things one at a time, and then "integrate" later, which is the way this kind of thing always seems to go.

Comment: Great picture & "example of what your final output might eventually look like"!

Comment: Thank you, and yeah you are of course right about it being a lot of questions. 
I ended up going to my local open space and discussing the ideas with them and they ended up recommending me to use an esp32 to hook it all up on and then get the electronics working first before attempting anything with the wood.

I will return with specific questions if I end up getting stuck at some point. Thank you for you answers.